# Make a div full width when is a child from display:table?

Tags: html, css, width, css-tables

As you can see in the snippet, the `div.detail` won't take full width, even that it's set to block and width: 100%.

How can I make a div full width when Inside a display:table?

Is there any workaround?

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 400px;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
}
.td {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.detail {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="td">Td</div>
    <div class="td">Td</div>
    <div class="td">Td</div>
    <div class="td">Td</div>
    <div class="td">Td</div>
  </div>
  <div class="detail">
    Lorem ipsum ad his scripta blandit partiendo, eum fastidii accumsan euripidis in, eum liber hendrerit an.
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="td">Td</div>
    <div class="td">Td</div>
    <div class="td">Td</div>
    <div class="td">Td</div>
    <div class="td">Td</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please note that the .td width's must keep flexible, and the table-row and table-cell **are required**, and the widths of the columns must be consistent among rows..

I tryied this and:

```
.detail { display: table-caption; }
```

Almost does it, but it changes the order of the elements..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, use display: table; on rows.

```css
.row {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;     
}

.td {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 1em 0;
}
.detail {
    width: 100%;
    background: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="td">Td</div>
    <div class="td">Td</div>
    <div class="td">Td</div>
    <div class="td">Td</div>
    <div class="td">Hey, I'm a sentence!</div>
  </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="detail">Lorem ipsum ad his scripta blandit partiendo, eum fastidii accumsan euripidis in, eum liber hendrerit an.</div>
    </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="td">Td</div>
    <div class="td">Td</div>
    <div class="td">Td</div>
    <div class="td">Look man, I'm a sentence too!</div>
    <div class="td">Td</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I've seen it fail several times if there's not a table-row between the cells and the table.. http://i.imgur.com/EjRbC0f.png (in this example, i just updated the content of one column, the sizes are not consistent)

Comment: Add table-layout: fixed; on .row element (?)

Comment: (typo fix) the problem, is that how are they going to be related? they are siblings and they don't have a parent table style in common..

Comment: It looks like is the best answer so far, with the table-layout (you might want to edit the answer before I acept it..)

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gm2h3yav/)

I have made some changes to CSS for td as

`.td {
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      width: 19%;
      float:left;
        display:table-cell;
    }`

Hope it will help.

Comment: Just some correction. If you are including float property then no need to include display property.

Comment: But i need the display:table-cell because i don't want to worry about the widths of the columns, thats the whole point to use display:table; I edited the question, removing the .td width, then you example doesn't work.. thanks anyway!

Answer (score -1):

```
    .td {
       display: inline-block;
       border: 1px solid #ccc;
       width: 19%;
       float:left;
    }
    .row {
       display: inline-block;
       width: 100%
    }
    // max-width is if you want responsive table cells
    .table {
       display: table;
       max-width: 400px;
    }
```

Added the .row css for better html rendering

Comment: And also, you're fixing the widths of the .td's, I don't want that... Please remove it from your fiddle, and it won't work

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="table">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="td">Td</div>
            <div class="td">Td</div>
            <div class="td">Td</div>
            <div class="td">Td</div>
             <div class="td">Td</div>
         </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="detail">
    Lorem ipsum ad his scripta blandit partiendo, eum fastidii accumsan euripidis in, eum liber hendrerit an.
  </div>
  <div class="row">
     <div class="table">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="td">Td</div>
            <div class="td">Td</div>
            <div class="td">Td</div>
            <div class="td">Td</div>
             <div class="td">Td</div>
         </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've seen it fail several times if there's not a table-row between the cells and the table.. http://i.imgur.com/EjRbC0f.png (in this example, i just updated the content of one column, the sizes are not consistent)